# Reaplaced AMQ with SQS using JMS but some property values in Message object are null

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

In some old project, I need to replace AMQ with SQS. The problem I have is when I'm receiving the message some "Message" attributes like (getJMSType()) are null for example:

inside the onMessage method I have:

```
@Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        LOG.info(CLASS_NAME, new Date() + " Message received... ");
        Converter.EVENT_TYPE eventType = null;
        String serviceType = null;
        try {
            if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                TextMessage txtMsg = (TextMessage) message;
                String onMessageRequestXML = txtMsg.getText();
              
                serviceType = txtMsg.getJMSType(); <----------------- THESE ONE
                if (serviceType == null) {
                    LOG.warning(CLASS_NAME, "JMS message type is null!");
                    return;
                }
                eventType = converter.getEventType(onMessageRequestXML);
                LOG.info(CLASS_NAME, "Message received is of EventType: " + eventType + " ServiceType : " + serviceType);

                if (serviceType.equalsIgnoreCase(ServiceConstants.MW_METER_MGMT_HOUSEHOLD_UPDATE_REQUEST_JMS_TYPE)) {
```

In my "message sender" code I set the message content and also the value for JMSType

example:

```
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(session.createQueue("nonprod-mbo-sqs-api-hybridcollection-dev-mwcfgsend"));

            String mes = "TEST...";
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(mes);
            message.setJMSType("MW_METER_MGMT_HOUSEHOLD_UPDATE_REQUEST_JMS_TYPE");
            message.setJMSMessageID(""+System.currentTimeMillis());
            producer.send(message);
```

In my project, I'm using amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib version 1.0.8.
Have also tried to use SQSTextMessage instead of TextMessage but the result is the same.

Any Idea why the values are not included when I receive the message?